# Sphere tangent to edges of cube

Tags: geometry, spheres

Does there always exist a sphere that is tangent to all of a cube's edges?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine how one could even imagine that there is not...

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes a figure is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I imagine a sphere whose center is the same as that of the cube.  There is clearly such a sphere tangent to the top $4$ edges of the cube.  By symmetry, it is tangent to all the others, also.